# Trying to generate random letters, but it keeps freezing on Line 10. What would cause this freeze? C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have been trying to completed a homework assignment in c# with the parameters as follows:

a) Write a program that creates a 5 x 5 array to hold a set of letters (chars).

b) Traverse this array and store random letters in each cell of this array

c) Make sure the program does not store the same letter twice while traversing. H

d) Output this 2d-array to the screen (another nested for-loop).

e) Now have the program repeatedly (i.e., using a while-loop) ask the user to type in a
coordinate (x, y) followed by a letter to be placed at that coordinate.

o Your program should replace the existing letter at that coordinate, but only if that letter
does not exist anywhere else in the array. If that letter already exists in the array, then
tell the user.

o Output the new array to the screen.

o Repeat this process until the user types a ‘-1’ for ‘x’ or ‘y’ in which case your program
should end.

I have had no trouble thinking of what to do and how to do it, however, my code keeps freezing for some reason. No error messages, no indicator of what the issue is. I want to know whats happening and why.

my code is as follows:

```
string[,] grid = new string[5,5];

Random rnd = new Random();
char randomChar = (char)rnd.Next('a','z');
int check = 0;
int leave = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++){
    for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++){
        grid[x,y] = randomChar.ToString();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                if (grid[i,j] == grid[x,y]){
                    check = 1;
                } 
            }
        }
        if (check == 1){
            y--;
            check = 0;
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Input a -1 when asked for row or column to exit program.");
while(leave == 0){
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++){
            Console.WriteLine(grid[x,y]);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Enter what row you want to alter: ");
    int row = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter what column you want to alter: ");
    int column = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if (row == -1 || column == -1){
        leave = 1;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Enter what letter you want to enter: ");
    string input = (Console.ReadLine()).ToLower();

    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++){
            if (input == grid[x,y]){
                Console.WriteLine("This letter already exists in the grid!");
            }
            else{
                grid[row,column] = input;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it stops while running, without an error message, and it doesnt stop running. It just sits there.

Comment: Since your set of random values is small you might consider just filling a container with all the letters, shuffling them, then taking them in order.

Comment: Do you mean `grid[x,y] = randomChar.ToString();`? I'm not sure why it would freeze there but I can say that you're only calling `Random.Next` once so how could you be generating more than one random number? Also, how could you need four nested loops?

Comment: If you need to make sure that there are no duplicates then just remove an item from the list of possibilities once you use it. Alternatively, keep a list of the indexes already used and then, when you generate a random index, check whether it is in that list. There's no need to traverse the whole 2D array every time you want to add a new element.

Comment: I'm afraid you took https://xkcd.com/221/ way too seriously... Can you please clarify how you expect to fill 5x5 grid with different values if you generate a *single* random string?

Answer (score 1):

Based on a cursory examination of the code in question, the real problem is that you do not vary the value of `randomChar` or otherwise generate more than one random character during the program execution.  Because the value of `randomChar` never changes during execution, the code goes into an infinite loop on the `for (y...)` because of the `y--` since `check==1` always evaluates to `true`

Try to step through the code using a debugger to understand what is happening.